# What is the purpose of a com.mongodb.connection.BufferProvider implementation

Tags: mongodb, driver

The PowerOfTwoBufferPool (which implements com.mongodb.connection.BufferProvider) comes up as a leak suspect in our application heap memory analysis every once in a while.

What is the purpose of this BufferProvider implementation? How does MongoDB driver utilize the ByteBufferS allocated by this instance?

How can we optimize this so it does not come up as leak suspect? - there is a constructor allowing passing of number N that will be raised as power of 2 (2^N) size buffer. But can we control this from the MongoDB driver configuration - is it necessary to optimize?